# Cambiar de estado un select a disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

Tengo este diseño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le doy al boton asignar el me guarda la información en una tabla de `sql` y necesito que el select se pongo disables y aunque le de actualizar a la pagina siempre permanezca `disabled`.

este es el `jade`

```
table(id='example-table' class='table table-fixed analisisD')
        thead
          tr
            th='Articulo'
            th='Descripción'
            th='Um'
            th='Ov'
            th='#Ubic'
            th='Teorico'
            th(class='vi1')='Conteo1'
            th(class='vi2')='Conteo2'
            th(class='vi3')='Conteo3'
            th='Dif'
            th='Dif $'
            th(class='vi2')='Asignar conteo'
            th='Seleccionar'
              input(type="checkbox" id='selectall')

          tbody(class='unico')
          if ListArticulos != undefined
            each Articulos in ListArticulos
              tr(class='Art')
                td(id='id_articulo' class='iarticulo')= Articulos.SI_Articulo
                td= Articulos.SI_Descripcion
                td= Articulos.SI_UM
                td= Articulos.SI_OV
                td
                  button(type='button' id='btn-analisisInterno' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal')= Articulos.SI_Ubicacion
                td= Articulos.SI_Existencia
                td(class='vi1')= Articulos.SI_Cantidad
                td(class='vi2')= Articulos.SI_Cantidad2
                td(class='vi3')
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif
                td= Articulos.SI_Dif_Dinero
                td(class='vi2 sel')
                  select(id='widthSelect' class='form-control widthSelect' name='mood')
                    option(name="0" value="0") -- Seleccione usuario --
                    option(name="1" value="1") 1020433143
                    option(name="2" value="2") 1026138136
                    option(name="3" value="3") 1037618420
                    option(name="4" value="4") 1128430921
                    option(name="5" value="5") 1152683886
                    option(name="6" value="6") 15255651
                    option(name="7" value="7") 43222012
                    option(name="8" value="8") 71268442
                    option(name="9" value="9") 71703960
                    option(name="10" value="10") 8463111
                    option(name="11" value="11") 98514535
                    option(name="12" value="12") 98643619
                    option(name="13" value="13") Admin
                td
                  input(type="checkbox" id='hola' class='case' name='case')
```

y de esta forma guardo al darle en el boton `asignar`

```
$(function() {
    $('.asignarConteo').on('click', function(e) {
        $('.widthSelect :selected[value!="0"]').closest("tr").each(function() {
            //console.log(
            //    $(this).find(".iarticulo").text(),
            //    $(this).find(":selected").text());
            var ar = $(this).find(".iarticulo").text();
            var usu = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            //alert(ar + usu);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/AsigUsuarios',
                method: 'post',
                data: { idArticulo: ar, Usuario: usu },
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        })
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas almacenar el estado del select en algún sitio. Puedes usar por ejemplo localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para este fin.

Otra alternativa que me parece mas correcta es que ese estado se almacene en la base de datos cuando actualizas, de esa forma cuando refresques el estado nuevo viene en la respuesta desde el servidor, y en el navegador sólo deberás interpretarlo.

Un saludo.